# como poderia diminuir a quantidade de if? visto que tem muito no meu código

Tags: python-3.x

Obs. Um erro crítico:
Na opção de selecionar operadores, uma vez digitado o operador de % é executada a função corretamente... Porém, dará ao usuário mais duas opções: "voltar" e "sair".  Em seguida, selecionando a opção "voltar", o programa retorna ao menu de operadores, mas, entretanto, digitando mais uma vez o operador % ele finaliza o programa. Ou seja, executa o break e print. Todavia, não há retorno da função "calcular_porcentagem"
**--RESOLVIDO-- na gambiarra!**

```
    import os
def logica_operador():
    while True:
        try:
            global operador
            operador = input('Digite um operador [+] [-] [/] [x] [%]: ')

            if len(operador) > 1:
                print('Digite apenas um operador!')
                continue

            if operador not in '+-/x%':
                print('Digite um operador válido!')
                continue

            if operador in '%':
                break

            numero_1 = input('Digite o primeiro número: ')
            numero_2 = input('Digite o outro número: ')
            numero_1_int = int(numero_1)
            numero_2_int = int(numero_2)

            if int(numero_1) and int(numero_2):
                print('Ok, tudo certo!')

            if operador in '+':
                print(f'{numero_1_int} somado por {numero_2_int} é igual a: {numero_1_int + numero_2_int}')
            elif operador in '-':
                print(f'{numero_1_int} subtraido por {numero_2_int} é igual a: {numero_1_int - numero_2_int}')
            elif operador in '/':
                print(f'{numero_1_int} dividido {numero_2_int} por é igual a: {numero_1_int /  numero_2_int:.0f}')
            elif operador in 'x':
                print(f'{numero_1_int} multiplicado {numero_2_int} é igual a: {numero_1_int *  numero_2_int:.0f}')

            entrada = input('quer "manter" em "%", "voltar" no menu de operadores ou quer "sair"? ')

            if entrada in 'manter' or entrada in 'MANTER' or entrada in 'Manter':
                return calcular_porcentagem()
            elif entrada in 'voltar' or entrada in 'VOLTAR' or entrada in 'Voltar':
                return logica_operador()
            elif entrada in 'sair' or entrada in 'SAIR' or entrada in 'Sair':
                print('programa finalizado!')
                os._exit(0)
            else:
                print('Você não digitou nenhuma das opções disponíveis!')
        except:
            print('O que digitou não foi um número!')
            continue

logica_operador()

def calcular_porcentagem():
    while True:
        global calcular_porcentagem
        numero_3 = input('Digite o número que deseja saber o resultado em porcentagem. Ex: (1000). ')
        porcentagem = input('Agora digite a porcentagem. Ex: (10%). ')
        numero_3_int = int(numero_3)
        porcentagem_int = int(porcentagem)

        if operador in '%':
            resultado = (numero_3_int / 100) * porcentagem_int
            print(f'{porcentagem_int}% de {numero_3_int} resulta em: {resultado:.0f}')

        entrada = input('Quer se "manter" em "%", "voltar" no menu de operadores, ou quer "sair"? ')

        if entrada in 'sair' or entrada in 'SAIR' or entrada in 'Sair':
            print('Programa finalizado!')
            os._exit(0)
        elif entrada in 'manter' or entrada in 'MANTER' or entrada in 'Manter':
            return calcular_porcentagem()
        elif entrada in 'voltar' or entrada in 'VOLTAR' or entrada in 'Voltar':
            return logica_operador()
        else:
            print('Você não digitou nenhuma das opções disponíveis!')

calcular_porcentagem()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
match term:
    case pattern-1:
         action-1
    case pattern-2:
         action-2
    case pattern-3:
         action-3
    case _:
        action-default
```

É possível adicionar uma estrutura switch-case como na descrita acima. Mas não vai diminuir a quantidade de linhas

Comment: Não tinha pensado na possibilidade, é uma alternativa, obrigado!

Comment: Apesar de não resolver o seu problema do tamanho do código, essa estrutura é mais performática.
Nesse caso não vai fazer muita diferença, mas em outros pode fazer.
Não ajudei muito mas o pouquinho que sei tentei compartilhar. Valeu mano, boa "codação" ai!

Comment: @joséguilherme Nesse caso vc só vai trocar 6 por meia dúzia. Vale lembrar que `match` tem uma semântica diferente de `if`/`else` (embora em casos específicos sejam equivalentes, [eles não são a mesma coisa](/q/497534/112052)). Dito isso, não entendo essa neura com "excesso de `if`". Se precisa testar N condições, cada uma com uma ação diferente, então vai ter N `if`'s, não tem muito o que inventar (até tem em casos específicos, mas pra um exercício simples não sei se vale a pena).

Comment: Só seria "excesso de `if`" se estivesse testando mais casos do que precisa (e aí se mudar pra `match` só trocou de problema, em vez de ter excesso de `if`, vai ter excesso de `case`). Por fim, se quiser uma sugestão de alternativa: https://ideone.com/nVZBe7 - Quanto a "ser mais performático", provavelmente a diferença é irrisória e imperceptível, e isso nem deveria ser o principal critério para escolher entre um e outro

Comment: me ajudou muito, valeu!

Comment: @hkotsubo Genial a sua alternativa!